# Introduce gap in path in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot a path using d3js by reading data from a file. However, there can be NaN values in there too. So, I need a gap in the graph at those points. Say there are 5 points 1,2,3,4,5 and I have values for 1,2,4 and 5 but not 3. So, there should be a path from 1 to 2 and a path from 4 to 5.

I came across a defined accessor for d3.line which does this for line elements. Any ideas as to how can I implement the same with a path.

Thanks in advance

PS: I am trying something like this:

```
var selection = d3.select(this)
                  .selectAll('.my-series')
                  .data(d);
selection.enter()
         .append('path');
```

Comment: `d3.line()` creates a *path*, not a line element.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado then what does d3.path do?

Comment: `d3.path` is for canvas. Are you using canvas or SVG?

Comment: I am using svg @GerardoFurtado
I've also edited the question to briefly describe what I'm trying to do

Comment: I still don't understand your question:  This statement `I came across a defined accessor for d3.line which does this for line elements. Any ideas as to how can I implement the same with a path` makes no sense.  A `d3.line` produces the `d` attribute for an svg `path`.  So your answer is to do what you are already doing.

Comment: @Mark I can't get the break in the graph. It just joins the two nearest points surrounding NaN

Answer (score 2):

Still not sure I understand the question, but I've written a code snippet below that demonstrates how to use the `defined` accessor of `d3.line`.  In this code, if either the `d.x` or `d.y` contain [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values, d3 will "break-up" the path line segment:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 200)
        .attr('height', 200);
        
      var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0,200])
        .domain([1,5]);
        
      var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0,200])
        .domain([0, 10]);
        
      var data = [
        {
          x: 1,
          y: Math.random() * 10
        },{
          x: 2,
          y: Math.random() * 10
        },{
          x: false,
          y: false
        },{
          x: 4,
          y: Math.random() * 10
        },{
          x: 5,
          y: Math.random() * 10
        }
      ];
      
      var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d){
          return x(d.x);
        })
        .y(function(d){
          return y(d.y);
        })
        .defined(function(d){
          return d.y && d.x;
        });
        
      svg.append('path')
        .style('stroke', 'steelblue')
        .style('stroke-width', 2)
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .attr('d', line(data));
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```